# teamcity github ssh connection hangs

Tags: github, ssh, teamcity

Using windows 8.1, teamcity 8.1.1, and github.
Used instructions from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) in conjunction with git extensions (git bash).
Uploaded the id_rsa.pub to my github account, uploaded the id_rsa to teamcity.

In the VCS setup screen, I used the ssh clone url, selected uploaded key, entered in my github username, and my passcode (same as my github password).

The test connection will always hang, and trying to go ahead and run a build will cause the agent to hang.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, use `git` as the username.